# curl does not work in EC2 instance due to some limitation?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I was running a crawling script on an EC2 server, and while reviewing the logs, I noticed that HTTP requests were failing. To investigate the issue, I attempted to run a curl command, but encountered the following error:

```
$ curl google.com
$ curl 142.250.199.110


curl: (28) Failed to connect to google.com port 443 after 131448 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Subsequently, after restarting the EC2 server, the script started functioning normally again.
(nslookup or dig are fine)

Could anyone help my questions?

1. Does AWS impose any rate limits?
2. How can I determine the cause of unsuccessful HTTP requests?
3. Why restarting server solve this issue temporary?

Comment: Curl should be fine in EC2. Could you run `curl -lvk http://www.google.com` and share the output

Comment: here it comes

```
curl -lvk http://www.google.com
*   Trying 142.250.207.36:80...
*   Trying [2404:6800:4004:824::2004]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2404:6800:4004:824::2004: Network is unreachable

```

Comment: @Halod
It returns an IP address suggests that DNS limitations are not a concern, right?

Comment: that is right. It shows that TCP handshake is failing. Does this EC2 have public IP (and is in a public subnet) **OR** using a NAT Gateway to reach out to internet? Additional checks recommended

1) Security Group Egress (Outbound) rules
2) Network ACL
3) Route-Table

Comment: Yes it has public ip in a public subnet and no NAT Gateway.
Security Group Outbound is allow all.
Network ACL is default.

It seems problem?

Comment: what strange for me is right after launch OS it works fine, however after few min or after few requests. it stops at all..

Comment: additionally I just set up new ec2(amazon linux 2023), and runs simple curl loop scripts. but it has same issue.

Comment: Since restarting the server fixes things (temporarily), your EC2 network settings are correct. The problem lies somewhere on your instance.

Comment: thats what I thought. but i just tried new EC2 instance, but same problem. It seems like VPC issue or some limitations I guess.

Comment: @esmanbo Even if you noticing in a newly created Amazon Linux instance also and this works intermittently, I have strong doubts on your Network ACL. I am assuming that rest all checks out. Could you test after making sure that both Ingress and Egress is having 0.0.0.0/0 allowed.

Comment: @Halod  is this correct?

100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 Allow
* All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 Deny

Comment: [screen shot ](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gifattemzlgfejkulwpvu/alc.png?rlkey=93s858h02lrz4dh1aty5an4fj&dl=0)

Comment: @esmanbo Thats looks correct on the Ingress. Do check the Egress too. Also share screenshot of Ec2 instance Security group, Route Table entries for the Subnet.

Comment: here it is!

[screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/9c2cbjysrik99kokui5ix/h?rlkey=dz93s2aiqqaxqec02zmvvuah8&dl=0)

Comment: I am guessing that the instance does not actually have an associated public IPv4 IP. Or it had one at launch but it was disassociated from the instance some time after launch/reboot. Note that being in a public subnet does not necessarily cause a public IP to be associated automatically. Also, check IPv6 settings. You may need to disable IPv6. Try ping instead of curl (because ping uses IPv4 by default).

Comment: @jarmod
This instance is associated with an Elastic IP, in this case it will not be disassociated  right ?

Comment: Correct, unless you have some automation that's disassociating it. Anyhow, I suspect that IPv6 may be part of this. Does ping (ipv4) work or `curl -4` (to force ipv4)?

Comment: thanks. however, actually I just tried with another account now. It seems fine so far.
Im pretty sure its not EC2's problem. It must be account or VPC problem.

Comment: ping or nslookup or ssh or other protocol are fine.

Comment: @jarmod curl -4 is same problem.